# Highcharts redirect is not working after print

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Hello I am new to highcharts in my application page we have number of charts and some data which is coming dynamically .When I am trying to print one highcharts it is appearing separately in page and one popup will be opened but when i save the pdf or print that graph then the page is not redirecting or showing the original page where number of highcharts and some data from database is exists. When clicked on back button it is unresponsive and showing wait. But this is happened only in chrome browser but in other browsers it is working fine.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor? It looks like some custom code works like this because by default after the print event the page is redirecting to the page where the chart is nested. You can test it here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

Comment: The demo which is showing above contains only 1 chart if did like that it is working fine for me also. But in our case in page we have two pie charts, 1 line chart and 1 bar chart are there. More over we have other section in the same page which contains some documents search results . Now these  charts and Documents list are all coming from Database. When I try to print 1 chart after printing it needs to show previous data but it is not happening in chrome. My application is in Asp.net MVC and I am using highcharts jquery library not https://dotnet.highcharts.com/.

Comment: My project contains number of projects with some redirections before it is coming to controller. so I can't paste my code here.

Comment: Seems that your app implementation has an impact for it, by default it works fine for page with multiple charts - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/86eL7u5t/

Comment: Page should contain multiple charts with other dynamic data. In my case I have two sections in the page with two partial views one view contains search results information   second view contains highcharts which shows different analytics for search results. So when i try to print it is any chart then that chart is showing then print is working after print is completed it should show search results also right with highcharts but the page becomes unresponsive after print is completed.

Comment: The Jsfiddle which you are mentioned didn't have any other dynamic data other than Highcharts. The page should have other dynamic data then it needs work.

Comment: I see, now it makes sense - try to use the `afterPrint` callback to inject previously fetched data into the chart - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.afterPrint

Comment: Thank you @SebastianWędzel I tried that also but what happens is When user clicked on Print print popup will come after that when user clicked on print another popup is appearing then the code inside the print is executing immediately but my page still in print screen only. Then when the  print is completed it is showing page unresponsive error.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not able to help without online reproduction of the issue that I will be able to debug on.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.

Instead of depending on Highcharts library.
I removed the left panel by using jquery $('#LeftpannelId').Remove() in highcharts print section.
When I clicked print on any chart so that after printing is completed it is reloading again with left document list.